gpg: No dirmngr although dirmngr is installed
I have used pass as an interface for gpg2 without problem so far on Ubuntu LTS 22.04 but suddently I cannot generate or edit new passwords:
$ pass edit newPW
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.dirmngr' failed: IPC connect call failed
gpg: error retrieving 'myemail@mailbox.com' via WKD: No dirmngr
gpg: myemail@mailbox.com: skipped: No dirmngr
gpg: /dev/shm/pass.O2kx0oYZ4uDsu/odi7xg-newPW.txt: encryption failed: No dirmngr

Following this other question I installed dirmngr:
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
sudo apt-get install dirmngr

There were error messages during the process (I have another issue with installing cuda packages that I decribed there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1520943/dependency-problem-when-trying-to-install-cuda-toolkit-11-8 but dirmngr seems to be installed:
$ apt list | grep dirmngr
dirmngr/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed]
dirmngr/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1 i386

A last note (if it can help solve the problem): .gnupg in the main directory is a symlink $HOME/Documents/dofiles/.gnupg
What shall I do?

I am not sure if what happened but I extended the expiration date of the gpg key following this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/813421/can-you-extend-the-expiration-date-of-an-already-expired-gpg-key (as well as reinstall Linux) and the problem could be resolved
